# Rails API / Ember-cli web app: what is the conventional workflow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, rails-api

In the process of building a SPA, we opted for a combination of Rails API and Ember-cli.

From what we understand, the architecture of the app will be the following:

- Rails API will run the back-end of the app, as an API
- Ember-cli will run the front-end of the app, as a front-end MV* framework
- Data will be served by Rails API to Ember-cli with JSON

What does not seem really clear though, is what should be the development workflow?

In other words, should we:

1. Build the back-end (rails models, etc), then build the front-end and finally connect both?
2. Build everything at the same time, but one feature at a time?
3. Go with another option?

Comment: I'd go Rails first because I'd create the API tests and make sure everything works as expected then I'd move to the frontend knowing all my API calls will work.

Comment: It seems this is also the workflow Tony Coconate in this tutorial: https://goo.gl/kMRnfZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend building both at the same time, in separate apps (that way you can test your API as an actual API rather than just a backend), but in close proximity to one another. This way you can make sure both play nicely with each other and you're getting the results you actually need, plus if something that you do on one causes an error on the other the bug will become immediately apparent.

Let me know if this answers your question enough, I can clarify/ give additional examples from here if you'd like.